# SSL issue with hosted Chef (12) (Windows)

Tags: openssl, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to set up `chef-client` to talk to hosted Chef (v 12) from Opscode but have encountered a SSL issues. I tried everything suggested on the net and stackOverflow (Including "`knife ssl fetch`" and adding "`ssl_verify_mode :none`") but nothing worked. I am running Windows 7. I have also tried switching / with \ in the paths in knife.rb and it did not work still.

Here is my output of running `knife ssl fetch`and `knife ssl check`

```
PS C:\Users\me\chef-repo> knife ssl fetch
WARNING: Certificates from api.chef.io will be fetched and placed in your trusted_cert
directory (c:\users\me\chef-repo\.chef\trusted_certs).

Knife has no means to verify these are the correct certificates. You should
verify the authenticity of these certificates after downloading.

Adding certificate for *.opscode.com in c:\users\me\chef-repo\.chef\trusted_certs/wildcard_opscode_com.crt
Adding certificate for DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA in c:\users\me\chef-repo\.chef\trusted_certs/DigiCert_SHA2_S
ecure_Server_CA.crt



PS C:\Users\me\chef-repo> knife ssl check
Connecting to host api.chef.io:443
ERROR: The SSL certificate of api.chef.io could not be verified
Certificate issuer data: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA

Configuration Info:

OpenSSL Configuration:
* Version: OpenSSL 1.0.1l 15 Jan 2015
* Certificate file: C:/projects/openssl/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.1p/ssl/cert.pem
* Certificate directory: C:/projects/openssl/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.1p/ssl/certs
Chef SSL Configuration:
* ssl_ca_path: nil
* ssl_ca_file: "C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"
* trusted_certs_dir: "c:\\users\\me\\chef-repo\\.chef\\trusted_certs"

TO FIX THIS ERROR:

If the server you are connecting to uses a self-signed certificate, you must
configure chef to trust that server's certificate.

By default, the certificate is stored in the following location on the host
where your chef-server runs:

  /var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/SERVER_HOSTNAME.crt

Copy that file to your trusted_certs_dir (currently: c:\users\me\chef-repo\.chef\trusted_certs)
using SSH/SCP or some other secure method, then re-run this command to confirm
that the server's certificate is now trusted.

PS C:\Users\me\chef-repo>
```

I am not sure what does the "OpenSSL Configuration" output mean, but I don't have any C:project dir (that is mentioned in Certificate File/Dir) on my machine. Could that be the issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy, I hit this error a while ago. I think you may be missing a cert for Ruby itself.

The short version, is you'll need to upgrade the cert and call it a day. Take a look at one of these guides:

https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550#the-manual-way-boring

1. knife ssl fetch
2. download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
3. put the cert into .chef/trusted_certs